# regex to match everything except one word

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to capture the following pattern "everything except data-extra"

Here is the search string :

```
<li data-extra="star" class = "result">a</li>
<li class = "result">b</li>
<li class = "result">c</li>
<li data-extra="star" class = "result">d</li>
<li class = "result">e</li>
```

And I would like to match only b, c and e (those without data-extra)

I've done something like this

```
<li(?!(data\-extra))class="result"(.*?)>
```

but this doesn't work (0 result with php preg_match_all)

Comment: Why regex? An HTML parser can do it easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`xpath_match_all`](https://gist.github.com/1358174) and

```
$results = xpath_match_all('//li[not(@data-extra)]', $htmlString);
```

If you want to explicitly include the class as well, change the [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) to

```xml
//li[not(@data-extra) and @class="result"]
```

The `$results` variable will contain the innerHTML and outerHTML of the found nodes.

Comment: hi, your solution is better, however I would like to know how can i have all li in div id = "results", i've tried //div[@id="results"]/li but this doesn't work (because li are embedded in ul first and others div)

Comment: @Bouki `//div[@id="results"]//li` will give all li elements below the div with the id attribute of "results". Please check the linked XPath tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the whitespaces in your regexp. Here comes one as .NET regexp:

```
\s+!(data-extra).+>(.+)&lt;/li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<li ([^data\-extra]).+>
```

seems to work - though I've only tested it here - http://regexpal.com/ and not necessarily against php.

There may well be a cleaner way to do it though.

Comment: OP doesn't want class character but exclude the string `data-extra`

Comment: You're right - I didn't read it very carefully.  <li (?!(data\-extra))class = "result"> works on the tester I was looking at, I think he was just missing the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way that uses regex, although an HTML parser is generally a better idea:

```
<?php
  $a = '<li data-extra="star" class = "result">a</li>
  <li class = "result">b</li>
  <li class = "result">c</li>
  <li data-extra="star" class = "result">d</li>
  <li class = "result">e</li>';

  preg_match_all('/<li(([^>])(?<!data\-extra))*>(.*)<\/li>/', $a, $m);
  print_r($m[0]);
?>
```